# Can I stack multiple different HATs on RaspberryPi4?

Tags: hardware, pi-4, i2c, hat, microphone

I want to use multiple different HATs on the same Raspberry Pi. These are the boards I want to use:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16328

https://www.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker-4-Mic-Array-for-Raspberry-Pi.html

https://www.tindie.com/products/cburgess129/12-bit8-channel-adc-hat-for-raspberry-pi-v30/

Is it possible to do that? IF it is, will I need to specify the addresses in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the ports each HAT will be using for the [ReSpeaker 4-Mic Array](https://www.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker-4-Mic-Array-for-Raspberry-Pi.html) and the [12-Bit/8-Channel ADC HAT](https://www.tindie.com/products/cburgess129/12-bit8-channel-adc-hat-for-raspberry-pi-v30/). But I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do so because of an overlap in the pins the HATs will be using.